# Firebase Google+ Sign In - after sign in button clicked, page refreshes and onActivityResult is never called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm using Firebase auth with Google+ Sign in, and once I click the sign in button, the page refreshes (?) and onActivityResult is never called...

Before anyone asks, Firebase Google Sign-in is enabled, my SHA-1 is added and is correct, and my google-services.json is added and up to date.

Some more strange behavior: after uninstalling my app and then re-running it, the dialog to choose a user came up after clicking the sign-in button. It disappeared after about 2 seconds and never came back up.

Relevant Gradle lines:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
```

Here's my LoginActivity.java code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    View.OnClickListener {


private static final String TAG = "GoogleActivity";
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

// [START declare_auth]
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
// [END declare_auth]

// [START declare_auth_listener]
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
// [END declare_auth_listener]

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private TextView mStatusTextView;
private TextView mDetailTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // Button listeners
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

    // [START config_signin]
    // Configure Google Sign In
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    // [END config_signin]

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    // [START initialize_auth]
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    // [END initialize_auth]

    // [START auth_state_listener]
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // [START_EXCLUDE]

            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    };
    // [END auth_state_listener]
}


// [START on_start_add_listener]
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}
// [END on_start_add_listener]

// [START on_stop_remove_listener]
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
// [END on_stop_remove_listener]


// [START onactivityresult]
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            Log.d("auth", "in activity result - failed");
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    }
}
// [END onactivityresult]

// [START auth_with_google]
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
    // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
    showProgressDialog();
    // [END_EXCLUDE]

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
}
// [END auth_with_google]


// [START signin]
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
// [END signin]


private void revokeAccess() {
    // Firebase sign out
    mAuth.signOut();

    // Google revoke access
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {

                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
    // be available.
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int i = v.getId();
    if (i == R.id.sign_in_button) {
        signIn();
    }
}
}
```

And the relevant XML:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:background="@color/transDarkGrey"
    >
        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        />

        <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/Gold1"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        />



    </LinearLayout>
```

I've tried to keep the code as close to the Firebase/Google Auth examples as possible to avoid issues, so I'm quite lost as to what is going wrong here. Here's my sign out code, just in case that is causing the issues:

```
    // [START configure_signin]
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new 
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    // [END configure_signin]

    // [START build_client]
    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
    // options specified by gso.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    // [END build_client]

    signOutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mAuth.signOut();
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Any help much appreciated

Edit: Just to add a little more info, the reason I'm doing more than

```
mAuth.signOut();
```

to sign out is because I need the subsequent log-in dialog to always ask which user to log in, and adding the extra sign out stuff was the only way I found to achieve that. Again, not sure if that code is relevant but hopefully it helps.

Comment: If you download and run the Firebase Quickstart app with no modifications and using the same device, does it work?

Comment: Currently trying to get the Quickstart up, running into an issue saying that there is a duplicate fingerprint...trying to work through that. Will let you know once I get it running

Comment: So while debugging in the Quickstart, I noticed that it at least reaches onActivityResult, which doesn't happen in my app. Hopefully that gives a clue. I'll try comparing them line-by-line and see what I can find.

Comment: I'm viewing all my revision history, and as far as I can tell there are no changes that could have caused this. Everything I changed since the last time it worked perfectly has been formatting. So, eliminating that possibility, it must be either 1) The new way I signed out caused this, 2) Selecting a different account to log in caused it, or 3) Something changed in the Firebase console, which is not likely as I haven't touched it in months.

Comment: @hatboysam Found some more interesting behavior. I changed some code so I manually put my Firebase user ID into the mAuth.signInWithCredential method, and it's failing auth.

Comment: Also, it looks like email authentication doesn't work either.

Comment: @hatboysam fixed for now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! I copied over the Quickstart code exactly and now logging in works. I don't know why yet, but I'll figure that out